# I can't initialize my UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, ibaction, iboutlet

I'm facing the following issue. I have a view with a `UINavigationBar` (not NavController) added with XIB, and on this bar a `ButtonBarItem`.

Now I want my button to print "Hello" in the console. This is my current code :

*.h*

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *boutonInfos;
- (IBAction)versVueInfos : (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
```

*.m*

```
@synthesize boutonInfos;
[...]
- (IBAction) versVueInfos : (UIBarButtonItem *) sender { NSLog(@"Hello"); }
```

But if I try to connect the button to the action *versvueInfos*, my app stops running when I click on the button with this error :

> -[UIViewController versVueInfos:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x60117f0 2012-05-19 13:54:36.512 EC[1405:207] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   versVueInfos:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60117f0'

When I try to connect the button to the outlet boutonInfos, same problem but my app even doesn't run :

> 2012-05-19 13:58:17.948 EC[1441:207] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key boutonInfos.'

So what am I doing wrong ? Sorry if this is very noobish, but I'm still a beginner in Obj-C/iPhone programming.

Comment: can you show the code where you are defining selector, also check your xib once for warnings, if there is any present?

Comment: I've no selector, and the compilator doesn't send me any warnings

Comment: have you added this action method in the xib itself?

Comment: I've added by a connection between the button and it (file's owner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the class of the xib file in interface builder.If it is of your viewcontroller class then it might work.... its a guess because in the error log its still showing uiviewcontroller  instead of your viewcontroller class name .check the files owner class in interface builder

Comment: Thanks for the advice... but no, my xib class is corrrectly set to MenuController instead of UIViewController. So I don't know...

Comment: I haven't done something particular to define it because I only have IB outlets... What should I do that I may have forgotten ?

Comment: check the xib and all outlets for any errors   because another reason is that sometimes after connecting the outlet to the button and after that if you change the name of the outlet in the .h and .m file also this can happen ,because in the xib the old name will be still there,check for outlets which are not connected,if everything seems to be right just clean the target and build again,and from the simulator also delete the app and build again new...not sure :)

Comment: I think my mistake was because of an incorrect using of the navigation controller... thanks a lot for your answers :)